# Mapping object with data from another table using foreign key with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, mapping

I am trying to populate the data within this class from a database using Hibernate and javax persistence annotations.  Here are the relevant database structures.

```
table Poss_resp     
ID  qst_id  resp_text
int int text

table Responses         
ID  qst_id  usr_id  resp_id
int int int int
```

I am trying to populate the Response class shown below with Responses.ID, and Poss_resp.resp_text.  Poss_resp holds possible answers to a question.  Responses holds the actual answers given.  resp_id is a foreign key for Poss_resp.  However, I just want the resp_text string stored, I do not want a whole new object.  Is there some way to achieve this?  I cannot figure out how to tell Hibernate how to use something other than Response's primary key, nor have I determined the proper JOIN syntax.

My Response class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="responses")
public class Response {

    private long id;
    private long qst_id;
    private long resp_id;
    private String resp_text;


    /**
     * 
     */
    public Response() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    @Id
    @Generated(value="assigned")
    @Column(name="ID")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }


    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    /**
     * @return the qst_id
     */
    @Column(name="qst_id")
    public long getQst_id() {
        return qst_id;
    }


    /**
     * @param qst_id the qst_id to set
     */
    public void setQst_id(long qst_id) {
        this.qst_id = qst_id;
    }


    /**
     * @return the resp_id
     */
    @Column(name="resp_id")
    public long getResp_id() {
        return resp_id;
    }


    /**
     * @param resp_id the resp_id to set
     */
    public void setResp_id(long resp_id) {
        this.resp_id = resp_id;
    }


    /**
     * @return the resp_text
     */
    public String getResp_text() {
        return resp_text;
    }


    /**
     * @param resp_text the resp_text to set
     */
    public void setResp_text(String resp_text) {
        this.resp_text = resp_text;
    }
```

If at all possible, I would prefer annotations.

Comment: Those JavaDoc comments seem, how do you say, less than useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship of `Responses` and `Poss_resp`  table is many-to-one , you should map this relationship in the  `Response` class . Otherwise , hibernate has not enough knowledge to get `Poss_resp.resp_text` given the `Responses.resp_id`

Your `Poss_resp` table should be mapped to an an entity class (say  Class `PossResp`)

Then , you can declare many-to-one relationship using the `@ManyToOne` and `@JoinColumn` , like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="responses")
public class Response {
   ..................
   private PossResp possResp;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "resp_id") 
    public PossResp getPossResp() {
        return possResp;
    }
    ................

}
```

To get the `resp_text` given an `Response`  object , call

```
 response.getPossResp().getRespText();
```

---

> I do not want a whole new object. Is there some way to achieve this?

If you only map the `long resp_id` instead of the `PossResp` object in `PossResp` entity , I am afraid that you have to manually write the HQL/SQL/Criteria to get the `resp_text` using the `long resp_id` and then set it back to the  `Response` via the `setResp_text()` setter  . But in this way, you definitely cannot enjoy the benefits provided by hibernate IMO.

Comment: Have learned that this is true.  Intermediate objects are indeed required.  Personally, I feel this wastes the table design, but I can always hide this behind another layer.